# discord.js bot won't mention a user

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm creating a discord bot using the discord.js v12.2.0+ library. Im creating a **!enslave** command which gets the bot to ping the target person once every 2 seconds 60 times. So for example `!enslave @Hello123` gets the bot to spam this "Torturing @Hello123 :evil:" but the bot doesn't if I do `!enslave 35203573250237` and it sends "Torturing undefined :evil:". The long number being the discord user's id.

This is my **enslave.js** code:

```
module.exports = {
    run: async(client, message, args) => {
        if(!message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
            message.channel.send("You don't have permission to use that command.");
        }
        else {
            try {
                let counter = 0;
                message.delete()
                let user = message.mentions.members.first() || await message.guild.members.fetch(args[0])
                console.log(args[0])
                let i = setInterval(function(){
                    const bot = client.emojis.cache.get('712787936734609419');
                    message.channel.send(`Torturing ${user} ${bot}`);
                    counter++;
                    if(counter === 60) {
                        clearInterval(i);
                    }
                }, 2000);
            }
            catch(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
    },
    aliases: [],
    description: 'Make ImmortusMC torture someone'
}
```

This is my **message.js** code:

```
const PREFIX = process.env.PREFIX;
module.exports = (client, message) => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;
    let cmdName = message.content.substring(message.content.indexOf(PREFIX)+1).split(new RegExp(/\s+/)).shift();
    let argsToParse = message.content.substring(message.content.indexOf(' ')+1);
    if(client.commands.get(cmdName))
        client.commands.get(cmdName)(client, message, argsToParse);
    else
        console.log("Command does not exist.");
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `message.guild.members.fetch(args[0])` instead of `message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])`.

The reason why you're getting `undefined` is that the member has not been cached yet so you can't get them using the `members` cache.

```js
let user = message.mentions.members.first() || await message.guild.members.fetch(args[0])
```

Comment: The bot replies with "Torturing [object Promise] :evill:" and as well I was logging args with console.log(args[0]) which logged 2 in the console.

Comment: You have to use `await` since it returns a Promise

Comment: Now I get "Torturing undefined :evil:" with `let user = message.mentions.members.first() || await message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])`

Comment: Sorry, my bad I just fixed the answer

Comment: Sorry the bot doesn't reply with any answer now, I get this in the console 
`DiscordAPIError: Unknown User
No debug adapter, can not send 'variables'`
I've updated my code to show what I have atm. This happens when I do **!enslave [userid]** and I definitely used the correct id as I did it three times. @Syntle

Comment: Which line is causing the error? Could you post the full error?

Comment: The try catch is catching the error and logging it to console, I updated my question with the image on bottom to show my console.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer, but ry:

`let user = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);`

You should use `.get()` when you are going to use the IDs. I also removed the `await` and added the `;` at the end.